# Page Navigation Outside the Loop

Tags: loop, navigation

I have a series of pages for individual products. I'd like to page between them using a navigation that sits outside of the loop.

```
               |              |
( <= prev )    |    <loop>    |    ( next => )
               |              |
```

I've tried `posts_nav_link`. I've tried `is_paged` conditionals within the loop. I've tried everything I can think of.

Anyone know how to accomplish this without hacking the hell out of WP?

Comment: Can you please update your answer with your code, not whole of it but your loop and the navigation snippets.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly is not working with both `posts_nav_link` and `is_paged`?

Comment: the same problem here, after page 10, I get 404 error in page navigation
after upgrading to WP 3.4 wp-pagenavi does not work anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

I use `previous_post_link()` and `next_post_link()` (Codex [previous_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link)/[next_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link)) outside of the Loop, with no problems.

Note that the Codex entries indicate that these functions must be used within the Loop, but IMX that isn't true. The functions call the `$post` global, and pass it to `get_previous_post()` and `get_next_post()`, respectively.

By the way, `posts_nav_link()` is the incorrect function to use in the single-post context, anyway. It is intended for navigation of *archive index pages*, not of single posts.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear on the question. But If it's navigation OUTSIDE the loop that you want. Then get [wp-pagenavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) and set it up however you want (prev/next only, or numbered navigation) and then simply call the following in the footer OR anywhere in the template files you want the navigation to show.

```
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
```